# Single Page App with Bootstrap and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, ember.js

I am new to javascript (although I've developed a small nodejs API server before, but it is nothing interactive, animating, or fancy at all)

I'd like to develop a static, single page website that works on modern browser and mobiles. The intended design looks a lot like

http://global.tommy.com/int/en/Collections/runway/spring-women

which is quite common with

1. Static Title Bar that follows wherever user scroll
2. < li > on the left acting like quick jump control + navigation/position indicator
3. carousel

I'm totally at blank on how to achieve such impressive look and feel and animation and responsiveness. So far, I tried out several libraries such as Twitter's BootStrap, Google's AngularJS, and AmberJS but none is as impressive as my intended outcome. The closest I get into is the sample from http://www.portalapp.com/ but that's my best trial.

Would any of you recommend any good resources (technology/libraries, or getting started guide and tutorial) to get off the ground fast?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

Do anyone has open source projects or sample on GitHub that uses any javascript/css libraries to achieve cross device, responsive, single page web app?

Please provide the breakdown of the libraries used as well., since javascript libraries are numerous

Comment: this article about single web app for angularjs may be you looking for `http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EmberJS has a nice guide from the official [website](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/). Their [API documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/) is also helpful. Moreover, you can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js) which is heavily documented.

If you need help, there are [community forums](http://discuss.emberjs.com/).

If you are into screencasts, here is one [free](http://www.toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/03/02/emberjs-rc1-introduction-screencast/) and one [paid](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs).

A word of caution using resources from Internet: EmberJS is in a "stabilizing" phase as they work towards version 1.0. So, if you read an old resource, it might not work using the current version of EmberJS.